# displaying the list items in reverse order using css

Tags: html, css

I am displaying the categories in my web page.Whatever I am adding from backend it is displaying in the list but I need the list in this format.

HTML:

```
<ul>
 <li>List 1</li>
 <li>List 2</li>
 <li>List 3</li>
 <li>List 4</li>
 <li>List 5</li>
 <li>List 6</li>
 <li>List 7</li>
 <li>List 8</li>
 <li>List 9</li>
 <li>List 10</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
transform: rotate(180deg);
}

ul > li {
-moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
transform: rotate(-180deg);
display:inline-block;
}
```

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqtdvhqa/) link

As of now it is displaying as

> List10 List9 list8 List7 List6 List5 Lst 4 List3 List2 List1

But for me it should display as in this format

> List6 List7 list8 List9 List10
>   List1 List2 list3 List4 List5

As of now i am having this list in my website

```
<ul id="legend">
    <li ><span>All</span></li>
    <li ><span>Church</span></li>
    <li ><span>Food </span></li>
    <li ><span>Fund&nbsp;Raisers</span></li>
    <li ><span>Games&nbsp;and&nbsp;Contests</span></li>
    <li ><span>Health&nbsp;and&nbsp;Wellness</span></li>
    <li ><span>Lectures</span></li>
    <li ><span>Movies</span></li>
    <li><span>Music</span></li>
    <li><span>Parades&nbsp;and&nbsp;Festivals</span></li>
    <li ><span>Seniors</span></li>
    <li><span>Sports</span></li>
    <li><span>Theatrical </span></li>
    <li><span>Visual&nbsp;Arts</span></li>
</ul>
```

Output should be as

> HealthandWellness Lectures Movies Music ParadesandFestivals
>   ParadesandFestivals seniors sports Theatrical Visual Arts
>   All Church food fundraisers games

Comment: did you try it with Javascript?

Comment: Any particular reason you are rotating your elements in that manner? Anyway, you can achieve the intended result by adding `display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: flex-end;` to your unordered list (`ul`).

Comment: To follow up on the comment by @UncaughtTypeError - You could also use the css flexbox orders to re-order the items in the list to your desired format. This would only work if you have 10 items in the list

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to reverse the order, you could use the `direction` property

```css
ul {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: left;
}
li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List 1</li>
  <li>List 2</li>
  <li>List 3</li>
  <li>List 4</li>
  <li>List 5</li>
  <li>List 6</li>
  <li>List 7</li>
  <li>List 8</li>
  <li>List 9</li>
  <li>List 10</li>
</ul>
```

But if you want to change it like this:

> List6 List7 list8 List9 List10 List1 List2 list3 List4 List5

You should use flex:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}
li {
  order: 2;
}
li:nth-child(n+6) {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List 1</li>
  <li>List 2</li>
  <li>List 3</li>
  <li>List 4</li>
  <li>List 5</li>
  <li>List 6</li>
  <li>List 7</li>
  <li>List 8</li>
  <li>List 9</li>
  <li>List 10</li>
</ul>
```

## EDIT

As commented, you are looking for two rows:

> List6 List7 list8 List9 List10
> List1 List2 list3 List4 List5

Then this should work:

Note that you need to define a width to the list-items to make the `flex-wrap` to work.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
li {
  width: 20%;
  order: 2;
}

li:nth-child(n+6) {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List 1</li>
  <li>List 2</li>
  <li>List 3</li>
  <li>List 4</li>
  <li>List 5</li>
  <li>List 6</li>
  <li>List 7</li>
  <li>List 8</li>
  <li>List 9</li>
  <li>List 10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I just saw that you want two rows... let me change that

Comment: are you sure about direction ? it's doing nothing

Comment: @TemaniAfif, it does, look in the source (1,2,3,...) and the result (10,9,8,...)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, if you run the snippet, then the result should be (10,9,8,...)... what browser are you using?

Comment: Order should be List6 list7 list8 list9 lst10 in the top and List 1 list2 list3 list4 lst5 in hte bottom

Comment: @user8725518 Then the last code snippet of this answer should have you covered.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError i have updated my question can you please check it once

Comment: Dude, why not ask it directly... and the given solution can be applied to that as well, if you tweak it a little. You might want to try some stuff yourself before asking...

Answer (score 1):

Use Flex-box. It is simply the simple. 
For reverse just:

```
ul{display:flex; flex-direction:row-reverse; }
```

For order u can use Flex-order:

```
ul {display:flex; } ul > li {flex:1; order:2;}
```

I have just creat a samples.

1. for reverse: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-direction/
2. for order: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Answer (score 0):

you have to split the list and arrange them by using order property. Here I have used width as 20% because you have 5 elements in the first row

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li:nth-child(n+6) {
  order: 1;
}
   
li {
  width: 20%;
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List 1</li>
  <li>List 2</li>
  <li>List 3</li>
  <li>List 4</li>
  <li>List 5</li>
  <li>List 6</li>
  <li>List 7</li>
  <li>List 8</li>
  <li>List 9</li>
  <li>List 10</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
ul {
list-style-type: none;
direction:rtl;
}
.abc{
text-align:right;
display:inline-block;
}
.lineB{
float:right;
}
.lineA{
float:left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="abc">
<ul>
    <li class="lineB">List 1</li>
    <li class="lineB">List 2</li>
    <li class="lineB">List 3</li>
    <li class="lineB">List 4</li>
    <li class="">List 5</li>
    <li class="lineA">List 6</li>
    <li class="lineA">List 7</li>
    <li class="lineA">List 8</li>
    <li class="lineA">List 9</li>
    <li class="lineA">List 10</li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check it now, is it ok ?

Comment: No i have updated my question can you please check it once